# Enumeration basics in C#

Tags: c#, enums

In Microsoft documentation about [enumerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-7.0) I found the following:

`public enum ArrivalStatus { Late=-1, OnTime=0, Early=1 };`

And it says:

> It creates an enumeration named `ArrivalStatus` that has three members: `ArrivalStatus.Early`, `ArrivalStatus.OnTime`, and `ArrivalStatus.Late`. Note that in all cases, the enumeration does not explicitly inherit from `Enum`; the inheritance relationship is handled implicitly by the compiler.

Question #1: Is `ArrivalStatus` a class created by this syntax, and specifically a subclass of `Enum` class?

Question #2: Enumeration members(`ArrivalStatus.Early`, `ArrivalStatus.OnTime`, and `ArrivalStatus.Late`) are actually instances/objects of `ArrivalStatus` class? Or how are these "members" connected to the class?
The syntax `ArrivalStatus.Early` implies that `ArrivalStatus` is a class and `Early` is a static property of that class. Is this correct? Please explain.

Further down one reads:

> The following example instantiates an `ArrivalStatus` whose value is `ArrivalStatus.OnTime`.
>
> ```
>    public static void Main()
>    {
>       ArrivalStatus status = ArrivalStatus.OnTime;
>       Console.WriteLine("Arrival Status: {0} ({0:D})", status);
>    }
> ```

In this example `ArrivalStatus.OnTime` is an object of `ArrivalStatus` class, specifically the value of an object, right?

Further down it says:

> As the following example shows, in this case the underlying value of the enumeration instance is 0. However, this is not necessarily the value of a valid constant in the enumeration.
>
> ```
> ArrivalStatus status1 = new ArrivalStatus();
> ```

Here, `new ArrivalStatus()` equals an 'enumeration instance', right? (that means an object of `ArrivalStatus` class).

Comment: Enums are not classes. If anything, they are closer to structs since they are value types.

Comment: Just FYI - if any of the answers works for you - feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

In C# an `enum` is not a class. An enum in C# is just a value, and in the case of `ArrivalStatus` as you have declared it, it is internally represented exactly like an `int`.

The syntax `ArrivalStatus.OnTime` might be a bit misleading, because it looks like referencing a member of a class; however, this is not the case. The name-dot-name syntax that we are already familiar with for referring to class members is just being reused in order to refer to one of the values of an `enum`.

So, `ArrivalStatus.OnTime` is not an object of `ArrivalStatus` class, it is an enum value of the `ArrivalStatus` enum, and it is equivalent to an int.

The `ArrivalStatus status1 = new ArrivalStatus();` clause is another unfortunate case where the syntax can be misleading. This looks like instantiating an object, but no object actually gets instantiated. C# just allows us to create instances of value types (`struct`s) in a way that looks like a constructor invocation, and since `enum` is a value type, it can also be instantiated the same way.  This way of creating an `enum` is superfluous and unnecessary; it can just be abbreviated to `ArrivalStatus status1;`. When `status1` is created this way, it will just receive the `default` value, which, if I remember correctly, is always zero, even if  `ArrivalStatus` declares no `enum` value that corresponds to zero. So, the declaration is also equivalent to `ArrivalStatus status1 = 0;`.

(Yes, although `enum` values are integral types, you normally cannot do integer arithmetic with them, but you can do one thing: assign zero to them.)

Comment: You can also apply binary OR to some enum values.

Comment: Additionally, you can convert other integer values, even ones that are not defined by the enum, to the enum type.  In the example above, `ArrivalStatus status1 = (ArrivalStatus) 37;` is valid.